# Not able to load the resource file in jar file(docker build). Locally working fine

Tags: java, spring-boot, resources, classpath, jks

I have a certificate file in jar with path `-BOOT-INF/classes/keystore.jks`. I have used `classpath:keystore.jks` with Resource to access the file. locally I am able to get the file and able to run the spring boot application.But when I build it and create a jar, I can see the file but I am getting below exception -

```java
FileNotFoundException: file:/libs/app.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/keystore.jks (No such file or directory)\n\tat j.io.FileInputStream.open0(FileInputStream.java)\n\tat j.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:219)\n\tat j.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:157)\n\tat c.s.i.o.c.f.HttpConnectionFactoryImpl.loadKeystore(HttpConnectionFactoryImpl.java:119)\n\t... 55 common frames omitted\nWrapped by: c.s.i.o.c.e.SSLContextException: Unable to load keystore / truststore /file:/libs/app.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/keystore.jks
```

I tried below things which are not working -

```
storePath = ((ClassPathResource)ebbsTrustStore).getPath()
  path = CheckKeytsotrePath.getInternalResource(storePath).getPath()
  ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:keystore.jks").getPath()
((ClassPathResource)ebbsTrustStore).getURL().toString()
```

I need this path to be passed to library method which is part of `BOOT-INF/lib` part in the same jar. Please let me know if you have any solutions/ hint for this.

Comment: did you check the permissions of this file? perhaps your not able to acess this file.

Comment: @Devilluminati yes permission is fine, no problem with permission